# Arduino Yun Parse Setup not working in Arduino IDE

Tags: parse-platform, arduino-uno, arduino-yun

I am using an Arduino Uno with the Dragino Yun Shield.

Everything is working perfectly fine until I go here at step 5:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/arduinoyun

```
WARNING: Category '' in library Parse Arduino SDK is not valid. Setting to 'Uncategorized'
Unable to find C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Parse_Arduino_SDK\examples\Arduino Yun\setup\setup.ino in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Parse_Arduino_SDK\examples\Arduino Yun\setup
```

Error compiling.

I don't understand. I got the files from the manage libraries tab as requested and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason it would not run from the default sketch directory that it was in. So I simply copied it to anther sketch and ran it from there.